# MySql: How to reduce execution time of this Query?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to customize this query, It takes around 30 Second to take out results, total records in 'videos' table are about 0.5 million, 3 million members are present in 'Members' Table, is there any alternate Query or should i break this query in 2 select queries ?

user_id is Indexed
vid_id  is Indexed

```
select a.ref_url , a.source , a.video_name , a.viewers , b.username ,           
c.points from 
members_videos a 
inner join Members b on a.user_id = b.user_id
inner join rankings      c on c.user_id = b.user_id

where a.cat_ids in (123,234,52,234,423,122) not in (110,99)
order by a.vid_id Desc limit 10
```

Comment: yes cat_ids and user_id are indexed

Comment: Having an index on cat_id may improve the performance

Comment: yes Madhivanan, it reduced speed upto 8,10 seconds when i have assigned indexed. but still too late

Comment: i think "NOT IN" makes it slower... because there are many records against 2 ID's

Comment: Try to use EXPLAIN http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html to get more information how it is executed.

Comment: The `not in` part is not necessary. If you take out the last line, how many records are you getting?

Comment: Without a schema and EXPLAIN, nobody can do more than guess.

Comment: Please fix syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple factors:

1. Make sure members_videos, Members and rankings have index on user_id column.
2. Break the query; eliminate Order By clause. Get the data in temporary table.
3. Select the data from temporary table and put Order By Clause over there.

Alternate, try sub-query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
select a.ref_url , a.source , a.video_name , a.viewers , b.username ,           
c.points from 
members_videos a 
inner join Members b on a.user_id = b.user_id
inner join rankings      c on c.user_id = b.user_id
where a.cat_ids in (123,234,52,234,423,122) not in (110,99)
) as T
order by T.vid_id Desc limit 10
```